# If S is a finite ring of subsets of X and μ is finitely additive on S, then μ is σ-additive on S.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I don't know how to approach this problem because I'm dealing with a finite ring and not a σ-ring, so S is not closed to countable union. If something is not clear sorry because english is not my first language. Any help is appreciated. :))

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hint: if $S$ is a finite ring of subsets of $X$, then any countable collection of disjoint sets in $S$ can only have a finite number of non-empty  sets. Since μ is finitely additive on S, can you now prove that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive on $S$?

Comment: Yes, yes thank you very much!!